# Is there any effect to an align directive immediately following another?

Tags: assembly, nasm, memory-alignment

How does it works exactly? does the last `align` override the behavior of the previously one making its effect null or does it do something when used together? I found this from a large assembly source code and I'm  asking this because I don't think it's just a typo.

```
align 64
align 4
```

Comment: if you did them in the other direction then yes that would matter but in this order no because an align 64 is by definition also an align 4

Comment: might be a case of someone adding more alignment later, but leaving `align 4` as a minimum so they could comment out the `align 64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align` inserts NOPs to bring the current section offset to a multiple of the specified value. (You can also explicitly specify a value other than NOP to insert, such as NULL padding). It does also implicitly call `SECTALIGN` to set the section's alignment attribute.

See [NASM manual section 4.12.12](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.12).

So it's a typo -- the second `align` will do nothing since the first one already padded up to 64-byte alignment. And the implicit `SECTALIGN` also has no effect since the manual specifies the alignment attribute can only be increased, never decreased.

Comment: Fun fact: `%use smartalign` / `alignmode p6, 64` will make more reasonable choices than just filling with single-byte NOPs.  (Which waste decode resources, and uop cache space, and can even over-fill one uop cache line, potentially being worse than leaving it unaligned if used inside a function where the NOPs execute.)