# What sequence can I write in NASM assembly to align the next label to a given alignment requrement

Tags: assembly, nasm, memory-alignment

We have here a case of some stuff where it would be really helpful to align something. Loks like this:

```
    [some code]
    ret
    db 0xCC
jump_label:
    [more code]
```

but I don't want to keep disassembling and adding/removing the db line to keep jump_label aligned. It should be on an even address. I used to know what the sequence was but I've lost it and can't find it with Google and only remember the sequence to fill to an absolute address (or relative to some other label) but not how to do the MOD N requirement. That sequence was:

```
fill_before equ $
    times some_constant - fill_before db 0
```

An answer is clearly superior if it doesn't introduce a unique label every time I have to write the sequence but an answer that does require a unique label is acceptable.

Note that the code is compiled with nasm -f bin so introducing sections wil not help.

Comment: [nasm has an align directive for this purpose](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.12)

Comment: And `%use smartalign` / `alignmode p6, 64` will make `align` use long NOPs instead of horrible single-byte NOPs.  YASM's `align` feature and options is implemented natively, not via a macro package, but unfortunately YASM isn't well maintained anymore.

Comment: Related: [Aligning a given instruction, but putting the alignment padding somewhere other than immediately before the instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50918578) is more more complex.  [Is there any effect to an align directive immediately following another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22489943) mentions the `align` directive but isn't really a duplicate.  Ah, found a real duplicate, [Align in assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63415138), although it's about data so it suggests `align 4, db 0`

Comment: @PeterCordes: They're "instructions" that will never execute.

Comment: Ok, then it probably doesn't matter much, if at all what size NOPs you use; I tried once or twice to test a scenario where parallel decode past a `ret` could maybe overflow the uop cache, but it didn't seem to happen.